# How do I find the range of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x) = \frac{3x^2}{x^2 - 25}$$

How do I find the range of the function? I found its inverse $$ x = \frac{3y^2}{y^2 - 25}$$
but don't know how to isolate $y$. Are there any other ways to find the range?

Answer (score 2):

We have $$f(x) = \frac{3x^2}{x^2-25} \Rightarrow x^2 = \frac{25f(x)}{f(x)-3}, \ f(x)\neq 3.$$
As $x^2 \geq 0$, we get $\frac{25f(x)}{f(x)-3} \geq 0$. If $f(x)>3$, we see that $25f(x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow f(x)\geq 0$ so $f(x)>3$. In the case that $f(x)<3$, we have $f(x)\leq 0$ so the range is $(-\infty,0] \cup (3,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Continue to solve for $y$:

First you have

$$x(y^2-25)=3y^2$$

so that

$$xy^2-25x=3y^2$$

Then gathering the $y$'s:

$$3y^2-xy^2=-25x$$

Then factoring yields

$$y^2(3-x)=-25x$$

Assuming that $3 \neq x$, then

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{-25x}{3-x}}$$

Comment: Note that we need to show that the function has a inverse first.

Comment: Your last equation is not quite right: $$|y|=\sqrt{\frac{-25x}{3-x}},$$ so the function is not invertible.

Comment: I was merely answering the question of how to solve from the point given. I'm going to assume given the level of question that they only need assume that an inverse exists. As for the absolute value dropping, I'm aware I did that. For the same reasons, I dropped it. The Common Core Math texts and others similar (which is around the level of the question) to not solve in that manner and I did not want to add confusion if it was possible to avoid it.